# Can I use a foreign key to the implicit rowid?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I want to create a database that supports "**friendships**".

I've come up with (but don't know exactly if it works):

```
users:
  "create table if not exists user (
    name text not null,
    password text not null
  )"
friendships:
  "create table if not exists friendship (
    user1 int not null,
    user2 int not null,
    foreign key(user1) references user(rowid),
    foreign key(user2) references user(rowid)
  )"
```

Will this work?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#parentchild) says:

> The *parent key* is the column or set of columns in the parent table that the foreign key constraint refers to. This is normally, but not always, the primary key of the parent table. The parent key must be a named column or columns in the parent table, not the rowid.

Please note that hidden `rowid` values are not guaranteed to keep their values (e.g., after a VACUUM), so in any case, it would be a good idea to make the parent key an explicitly named column.